# What is difference between Yao's "Garbled Circuit" and ther "Garbling Scheme" given by Bellare et al?

Tags: multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

What is difference between Yao's "Garbled Circuit" and the "Garbling Scheme" given by Mihir Bellare, Viet Tung Hoang and Phillip Rogaway in *"Foundations of garbled circuits"*?

I also want to know is it possible to use the garbling scheme / garbled circuit for multi party computation or it is only for 2 party computation.

Link for garbling scheme is given in :
Mihir Bellare, Viet Tung Hoang, and Phillip Rogaway. 2012. Foundations of garbled circuits. In Proceedings of the 2012 ACM conference on Computer and communications security (CCS '12). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 784-796. DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2382196.2382279

Answer (score 2):

Yao's garbled circuits is a generic protocol for two-party computation, which uses garbled Boolean gates along with oblivious transfer in a specific two-round protocol with a generator and an evaluator. Bellare, Hoang, and Rogaway's paper proposes a security model for garbling schemes themselves (i.e. the operation performed on individual gates in Yao's protocol) along with some constructions of garbling schemes.

Yao's protocol can be generalized to multiple parties, but those settings are usually better served by a protocol that generically supports many parties, such as GMW.